# Bind threads to specific CPU cores using OpenMP

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, cpu, openmp

I know that **GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY** binds threads to specific cores.

But in example what they have given [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html), it gives:

**GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 3 2 1"**

Here,

**thread0** gets attached to---> **cpu0**

**thread1** gets attached to---> **cpu3**

**thread2** gets attached to---> **cpu2**

**thread3** gets attached to---> **cpu1**

This is clear.

**But How can I set thread0 to core0 and core2 at same time ? What will be the value of Environment variable "GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY" for it ?**

Answer (score 4):

This [GOMP reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html) may help you. To answer your specific question `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-2:2 ..." would do that - it means "run on any processor 0-2, that is divisible by 2 (which is 0 and 2)".

At least if you are asking how you can let thread0 run on EITHER of core0 or core2 - the question you actually ask has the answer "you can't", because a thread can only be run on one core at any precise moment in time, so Thread0 can not run on two cores simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that CPUs 0 and 2 are hyperthreads of the same physical core, as well as CPUs 1 and 3. Intel's OpenMP library allows binding each thread to both hyperthreads with setting similar to:

```
KMP_AFFINITY="granularity=core,compact"
```

Unfortunately neither GCC (via `libgomp`) nor Sun/Solaris Studio allows one-to-many or many-to-many thread-to-cpu binding style. Setting `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` (GCC) or `SUNW_MP_PROCBIND` (Sun/Solaris Studio) allows each thread to be bound to a specific CPU but not to a set of CPUs.

With OpenMP runtimes that do not support binding styles similar to the one that Intel OpenMP supports, one can use the OS scheduler calls instead in order to modify each thread's affinity mask. This creates non-portable applications but allows to realise one-to-many binding styles. On Linux the necessary scheduler calls are [sched_getaffinity(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_getaffinity.2.html) and [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html).

Comment: @MatsPetersson, the `libgomp` reference is not wrong and if you read it carefully you would find out that the original poster's question of biding one thread to two different CPUs is unsolvable through the means of setting `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something here... Is this one of those "make the hyperthreading not hyperthreading type thing?

Comment: @MatsPetersson, unless the OP clarifies what kind of CPU he has, I can only make the educated guess that these are hyperthreads. Otherwise I'm not aware of any OpenMP runtime which allows arbitrary thread-to-many-CPUs bindings (with Intel's being exception that it allows binding of a thread to all hyperthreads of a single core).